# Retrofit2 Passing List as Url parameter

Tags: retrofit2

I am trying to make a GET request with a string list.

Retrofit representing list like this;

```
/endpoint?GTIN=111&GTIN=222
```

But server (Springboot) only giving results for the last one.

It works with this

```
/endpoint?GTIN=111,222
```

Is there a way of doing the latter in retrofit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with Retrofit's `@Url` annotation to produce the required URL.

In your service interface file do the changes to your API method,

```java
public interface YourServiceInterface {

    @GET()  // DO NOT pass any arguments here
    Call<YourResponseObject> foo(@Url String url);  // use @Url annotation here

}
```

In your Activity or Fragment.

```java
String url = BASE_URL + "/endpoint?GTIN=111,222";   // https://example.com/endpoint?GTIN=111,222

YourServiceInterface api = ....;

Call<YourResponseObject> call = api.foo(url);

call.enqueue(/* implementation */);
```